# How do you get the current target on panmove?

Tags: hammer.js

When using hammer.js, how do you get the current target on panmove?

In it's docs it states "Target: Target that received the event".

I'm using the panmove event but the target never updates. It only captures the initial target when pan starts. I would like to capture the current target as you pan over different areas (targets).